# Explicit examples of non-stabilizer (non-additive) quantum codes with recovery procedure

Tags: error-correction, resource-request

I am looking for resources that give an explicit example of a non-stabilizer code along with an explicit recovery procedure, i.e., syndrome measurement followed by correction operation for that code.

Most of the resources I have come across talk about general cases and don't give any explicit examples, and the ones that provide explicit examples of codes, don't talk explicitly about the recovery procedure, i.e., what syndrome measurement to perform and which measurement outcome corresponds to which error has occurred or which correction operation to perform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** For non-additive quantum codes constructed from a stabilizer code using the *union stabilizer code* construction, one can employ a two-stage syndrome acquisition circuit. The first stage is any syndrome acquisition circuit for the underlying stabilizer code (sans measurements) and the second stage is a quantum circuit that implements a classical function that removes dependence of the syndrome on the logical state. The second stage eliminates entanglement between the syndrome register and the logical qubit before the syndrome is measured.

### Example code

Many non-stabilizer codes can be constructed as the direct sum of translations of the code subspace of a stabilizer code. This is called the union stabilizer code construction. In the simplest case the stabilizer code is $[\![n,0]\!]$, i.e. a stabilizer state. For concreteness, consider the $[\![16,1,4]\!]$ surface code and let $|0;z_6\dots z_0,x_{7}\dots x_0\rangle$ denote the unique state of sixteen qubits that is the simultaneous $+1$ eigenstate of the standard logical $Z_L$ operator, $(-1)^{x_i}$ eigenstate of the $i$th standard $X$-type stabilizer generator and $(-1)^{z_i}$ eigenstate of the $i$th standard $Z$-type stabilizer generator. In the standard surface code the bitstrings $z_6\dots z_0$ and $x_7\dots x_0$ are the syndrome and are zero in the absence of noise. A decoder, e.g. based on the Minimum Weight Perfect Matching algorithm, uses this information to diagnose errors.

Now, consider the subspace $\mathcal{C}$ spanned by $|0_L\rangle:=|0;0\dots 0,0\dots 0\rangle$ and $|1_L\rangle:=|0;1\dots 1,1\dots 1\rangle$. This is an example code one obtains following the union stabilizer code construction.

### Syndrome sanitization

How can we diagnose errors in $\mathcal{C}$? Clearly, we can't measure any of the usual fifteen stabilizer generators as that would tell us the logical state. Still, there is no harm in applying the unitary $U_R$ that computes the bitstrings $z_6\dots z_0$ and $x_7\dots x_0$ and stores them in a fifteen-qubit register $R$. In the general case, $U_R$ comes from the stabilizer code employed in the union stabilizer code construction. This is our first stage syndrome register. Next, we sanitize the syndrome by eliminating its dependence on the logical state. In our case, this can be achieved by applying to register $R$ and a second fifteen-qubit register $S$ the unitary that implements the following classical function in the computational basis

```
if popcount(R) > 7:
    S = ~R
else:
    S = R
```

where `popcount` computes the Hamming weight and `~` applies a bitflip to all qubits. Here, $S$ is our second stage syndrome register. Finally, remembering that $R$ is still entangled with the logic qubit, we uncompute $R$ by executing $U_R^\dagger$. At this point, we can safely measure the register $S$ to obtain the syndrome that can be fed into a decoder. Subsequently, we can recover by active error correction or we can track errors in the control system using the Pauli frame.

A key step in the procedure above is syndrome sanitization which removes entanglement between the syndrome and the logical qubit. This allows us to use any syndrome extraction circuit for the underlying stabilizer code. In order to see how it works, let's assume that our logical qubit $L$ is in the state $\alpha|0_L\rangle+\beta|1_L\rangle$ and consider noiseless operation. In this case, $U_R$ puts $L$ and $R$ into the state
$$
\alpha|0_L\rangle|0\dots 0_R\rangle+\beta|1_L\rangle|1\dots 1_R\rangle.
$$
Next, the conditional statement with `popcount` turns it into
$$
(\alpha|0_L\rangle|0\dots 0_R\rangle+\beta|1_L\rangle|1\dots 1_R\rangle)\otimes |0\dots 0_S\rangle
$$
where the second stage syndrome register is not entangled with the logical qubit. Now suppose a single-qubit error occurred. In this case, the first stage syndrome in $R$ corresponding to $|0_L\rangle$ will have Hamming weight at most four and that corresponding to $|1_L\rangle$ will have Hamming weight at least eleven and, as before, one will be the bitwise complement of the other. Once again we see that the logic shown in the code snippet above ensures that $S$ is not entangled with the logical qubit and contains valid syndrome ready to be fed into a decoder.

### Caveat

It turns out that the quantum error correcting code above is actually equivalent to a stabilizer code. However, the error diagnostics procedure above made no use of its stabilizer structure. In fact, the procedure applies to all non-additive codes obtained using the union stabilizer code construction, although the classical function that obtains the second stage syndrome information is code-dependent and typically more complicated than in the example above.

### Reference

For a more formal description of this procedure, see section $10.5.2$ of *Quantum Error Correction* edited by Daniel A. Lidar and Todd A. Brun.

Comment: Another great answer, as always! Thank you. I really appreciate your contributions here!